# New Window (ctrl+n) is disabled in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I press ctrl+n to get a new window in the Windows File Explorer on my new Windows 10 laptop I am presented with this
[error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD3JP.png).

Transcription: "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator."

My system administrator has no idea why this is happening and didn't disable this deliberately.

I have local admin rights on this machine, is there a registry key or something I can edit in order to re-enable this shortcut?

I couldn't find this documented anywhere. There are reams of "howtogeek"-type webpages listing that ctrl+n opens a new window, but I couldn't find anything that described disabling or enabling that shortcut.

I couldn't find any useful docs for File Explorer either.

Comment: It looks like this question belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Yeah fair one. The error message mentions system administrators, and so does this site, but that's just dumb pattern-matching from me there. Happy to move it over if you reckon it sits better over there.

Comment: **My system administrator has no idea why this is happening and didn't disable this deliberately.** - Did they actually verify that this hasn't been disabled in Group Policy? The setting is under User Configuration>Policies>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>File Explorer>Turn off Windows +X hotkeys

Comment: Is Ctrl+N a Windows+X hotkey? The docs for that Group Policy entry list Windows+R, and Windows+E, but no Ctrl hotkeys. I can't see that setting in the gpresult output, but I'll check with IT regardless.